# For loop with dynamic range/borders

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, dynamic, range

I want to use the code below to loop through a range of cells and check whether the "Testword" is in one of those cells. If yes, a new row is inserted and all the cells underneath are moved one cell down. Now the problem is, that I'm using `j = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row` to determine the second counter of the for-loop and this counter doesn't change with the movement through insertion of new rows each time "Testword" is found. Thus, cells with values that must be checked move beyond the borders and "miss" the loop.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
        
    j = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = 1 To j

        If Range("A" & i) = "Testword" Then
            Range("A" & i + 1).Insert
    
        End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
        
    j = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = j To 1 Step -1

        If Range("A" & i) = "Testword" Then
            Range("A" & i + 1).Insert
    
        End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the next way, please. It will be **faster**, inserting everything at the end, at once:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rngIns As Range
        
    j = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'it will work even with gaps in A:A column

    For i = 1 To j
        If Range("A" & i) = "Testword" Then
            If rngIns Is Nothing Then
                Set rngIns = Range("A" & i + 1)
            Else
                Set rngIns = Union(rngIns, Range("A" & i + 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not rngIns Is Nothing Then
        'solving cases of consecutive rows keeping the searched string:
        If InStr(rngIns.Address(0, 0), ":") > 0 Then _
                   Set rngIns = makeDiscontinuu(rngIns)
        rngIns.EntireRow.Insert
    End If
End Sub

Function makeDiscontinuu(rng As Range) As Range
   Dim a As Range, c As Range, strAddress As String
   For Each a In rng.Areas
        If a.cells.count = 1 Then
            strAddress = strAddress & a.Address(0, 0) & ","
        Else
            For Each c In a.cells
                strAddress = strAddress & c.Address(0, 0) & ","
            Next c
        End If
   Next a
   Set makeDiscontinuu = Range(left(strAddress, Len(strAddress) - 1))
End Function
```

Comment: I didn't think it would make that much difference... But I did a test to see. ~35 rows of data where 14 is "testrow". Forloop backwards took 4.11 seconds. While loop took 3.84 seconds. This answer 0.34 seconds. It loooks counter intuitive to write so much code. However.... setting screenupdating and calculations to false/manual and running the forloop gave me 0.48 seconds.

Comment: While loop with false/manual is 0.4 seconds. And actually it takes the same time with or without adding any rows. I made a typo in the sheet so it says testword instead of Testword. When I ran the code with the typo nothing changed (obviously) but the time was still 0.4 seconds.

Comment: @Andreas: The difference can be much bigger if the range to be processed is really big and occurrences, too. And even faster if the case of consecutive rows is very rare. For such a case it can be made even faster, iterating through an array and build the cell range according to the iteration row number. But not a big gain...

Comment: Actually. I beg to differ... 10072 rows of copy paste of the previous test scenario. While loop took 11.2 seconds. your code didn't finish at all. It crashed at the set makeDiskcontinuu = range.... (last line of function). Not sure if the string got to long or what happened... 1004 (translated) Method range in objec _global failed. (or something like that). But it took far longer than 11 seconds. Possibly ~30 when it crashed... strAddress has 24 365 characters when it crashed, it looks OK but something does not work at that point. Perhaps range has a limit (?)

Comment: @Andreas: Yes. The address string has a limitation of 256 characters. That's why I preferred Address(0, 0), to save some characters... :) Can you make some speed test without consecutive rows occurrences?

Comment: Ok... Same test scenario I just looped through it prior and replaced with foobar if two testword appeared after eachother. so 10072 rows resulted in 13607 rows after this code ran, so... 3530-ish rows with testword. 54.64 seconds.... (just to be clear the loop to write foobar was not part of the time it took to finish)

Comment: @Andreas: Now I do not have too much time, but when I will be at home I will try a workaround to overpass the limitation of 256 string characters number. Only for the sake of finding a way...

Comment: @Andreas: I found a way to overpass the string limitation. Just for the sake of trying, understanding and playing with VBA. I will post another answer with both variant and my statistics of code duration, for the same range, with the same number of occurrences...

Answer (score 1):

Go backwards...

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
        
    j = Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row

    For i = j To 1 step -1

        If Range("A" & i) = "Testword" Then
            Range("A" & i +1).Insert
    
        End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Or use a while loop (less effecient)

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1
    while i < Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

        If Range("A" & i) = "Testword" Then
            Range("A" & i + 1).Insert
    
        End If
        i = i +1
    wend

End Sub
```

This will update the loop on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas, please look at this pair of codes. The more complicated code still works faster, but something strange happens. I mean, if you run each code after you save (somehow refresh the Application/VBA/whatever...) the running time has a minimum. Then, after each pair of runs some additional seconds (milliseconds, at least) are added. So, please try the next pieces of code and confirm that they behave the same on your installation.

I tested both codes on a range of 8700 rows, with 1216 searched string occurrences:

```
Sub Macro1Simple()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long', dTime As Double
    
    j = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'changed the way of calculation, for the case of inserted rows existence. 
    On Error Resume Next
     Range("A1:A" & j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    j = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    'dTime = MicroTimer 'to measure duration
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    For i = j To 1 Step -1

        If Range("A" & i) = "Testword" Then
            Range("A" & i + 1).Insert
        End If
    
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    'MsgBox (MicroTimer - dTime) * 1000 & " [ms]"
    'Refresh
End Sub
```

The complicated version:

```
Sub Macro1_Complicated()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rngIns As Range, arrRng() As Range', dTime As Double
        
    j = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'it will work even with gaps in A:A column
    On Error Resume Next
     Range("A1:A" & j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete: '  Stop
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    j = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    'dTime = MicroTimer 'to measure duration
    
    For i = 1 To j
        If Range("A" & i) = "Testword" Then
            If rngIns Is Nothing Then
                Set rngIns = Range("A" & i + 1)
            Else
                Set rngIns = Union(rngIns, Range("A" & i + 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If Not rngIns Is Nothing Then
        If InStr(rngIns.Address(0, 0), ":") > 0 Then _
                   arrRng = makeDiscontNoLimit(rngIns)
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        End With
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrRng)
            arrRng(i).EntireRow.Insert
        Next i
         With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End With
    End If
    'MsgBox (MicroTimer - dTime) * 1000 & " [ms]"
    'Refresh
End Sub

Function makeDiscontNoLimit(rng As Range) As Variant
   Dim a As Range, c As Range, strAddress As String, strAddr() As Range, i As Long, k As Long
   Dim arNo As Long
   
   ReDim strAddr(100)
   For Each a In rng.Areas
        If a.cells.count = 1 Then
            strAddress = strAddress & a.Address(0, 0) & ","
            If Len(strAddress) >= 256 Then
                For i = Len(strAddress) - 1 To 1 Step -1
                    If Mid(strAddress, i, 1) = "," Then
                        Set strAddr(k) = Range(left(strAddress, i - 1)): k = k + 1
                        strAddress = Mid(strAddress, i + 1, Len(strAddress) - i): Exit For
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Else
            For Each c In a.cells
                strAddress = strAddress & c.Address(0, 0) & ","
                If Len(strAddress) >= 256 Then
                    For i = Len(strAddress) - 1 To 1 Step -1
                        If Mid(strAddress, i, 1) = "," Then
                            Set strAddr(k) = Range(left(strAddress, i - 1)): k = k + 1
                            strAddress = Mid(strAddress, i + 1, Len(strAddress) - i): Exit For
                        End If
                    Next i
                End If
            Next c
        End If
   Next a
   If Not strAddr(0) Is Nothing Then
        Set strAddr(k) = Range(left(strAddress, Len(strAddress) - 1))
        ReDim Preserve strAddr(k)
        makeDiscontNoLimit = strAddr: Exit Function
   Else
        Set strAddr(0) = Range(left(strAddress, Len(strAddress) - 1))
        ReDim Preserve strAddr(0)
        makeDiscontNoLimit = strAddr
   End If
End Function
```

I could create a function to process the repetitive part of putting the (limited address) range in the array, but I only wanted to see it working on big ranges.

So, in order to avoid the duration increase after each run, I tried `Refresh` but without any result. Can you imagine a way to make VBA run with the same efficiency for all runs?

I measured the time using API `getFrequency` combined with `getTickCount`. but i do not think it is a matter of time measuring. I did not place the API functions and the necessary `Sub`, to let you use your way of measuring...